# Exibir apenas pai ou filho em uma busca por Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

sou iniciante no mundo do Elastic e tenho algumas dúvidas quanto aos relacionamentos.

Tenho configurado no meu mapping a seguinte relação:

```
"relacao":{
    "type": "join",
    "relations":{
       "pai":"filho"
    }
}
```

Segue um exemplo de doc filho: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTwXn.png

E um do doc pai: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjvic.png

Ao realizar uma busca, como os produtos possuem o mesmo nome o correto do Elastic seria exibir os dois (pai e filho)? Caso eu queria que apareça somente um deles, e de preferência sempre o produto com estoque, é possível?

Elasticsearch 6.4
PHP 7.2